# Python (soup): get nested data and get last item in a tag

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

So I have an html document that looks something like this:

```
<title>Speaker Name: Title of Talk | Subtitle | website.com</title>

... [Other Stuff]

<div class='meta'><span class='meta__item'>
Posted
<span class='meta__val'>
Jun 2006
</span></span><span class='meta__row'>
Rated
<span class='meta__val'>
Funny, Informative
</span></span></div>

<div class='talk-article__body talk-transcript__body'> TEXT 

<data class='talk-transcript__para__time'>15:57</data>
```

I have 2200 files like this, and I am hoping to put them all into a CSV file with columns of AUTHOR, TITLE, DATE, LENGTH, and TEXT. Right now, what I have is not the prettiest code, but it works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

soup = soup(open(file).read(), "lxml")
at = soup.find("title").text
author = at[0:at.find(':')]
title  = at[at.find(":")+1 : at.find("|") ]
text = soup.find("div", attrs={ "class" : "talk-article__body"}) # still needs cleaning
date = 
length =
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get at the date: I suspect it's a combination of `soup` and `re`, but I confess that I can't wrap my head around the combination.

The trick with the length is that what I want to find is the LAST time `<data class='talk-transcript__para__time'>` occurs in the file and grab THAT value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
date_spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'meta__val'})
date = [x.get_text().strip("\n\r") for x in date_spans if re.search(r"(?s)[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+\d{4}", x.get_text().strip("\n\r"))][0]
print(date)
#date = re.findall(r"(?s)<span class=.*?>\s*([A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+\d{4})", str(soup))

length_data = soup.find_all('data', {'class' : 'talk-transcript__para__time'})
length = [x.get_text().strip("\n\r") for x in length_data if re.search(r"(?s)\d{2}:\d{2}", x.get_text().strip("\n\r"))][-1]
print(length)
#length = re.findall(r"(?s).*<data class=.*?>(.*)</data>", str(soup))
```

**Output**

```
Jun 2006
15:57
```

Comment: That is outstanding! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex for the date  if the first meta__val is the date, you definitely don't need it for the time as you can just use the class name `talk-transcript__para__time`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = """<title>Speaker Name: Title of Talk | Subtitle | website.com</title>
<div class='meta'><span class='meta__item'>
Posted
<span class='meta__val'>
Jun 2006
</span></span><span class='meta__row'>
Rated
<span class='meta__val'>
Funny, Informative
</span></span></div>

<div class='talk-article__body talk-transcript__body'> TEXT

<data class='talk-transcript__para__time'>15:57</data>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(h,"html.parser")
date = soup.select_one("span.meta__val").text
time = soup.select_one("data.talk-transcript__para__time").text
print(date, time)
```

Output:

```
 (u'\nJun 2006\n', u'15:57')
```

If you were using a regex you would pass it to find or find_all:

```
r = re.compile(r"(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+\d{4}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")
date = soup.find("span", {"class": "meta__val"}, text=r).text.strip()
```

Which would give you:

```
'Jun 2006'
```

Comment: well the input was such that, you found the date first..see there are two `<span class='meta__val'>` in input..also OP mentioned that _I want to find is the LAST time <data class='talk-transcript__para__time'>_

Comment: Makes no difference, the html is parsed in order so the first is always going to be found first

Comment: that's what I am saying..see both of  them contains different text(one has date)..what would have happened if text in span classes were reversed

Comment: @rock321987, the first line of my answer, *You don't need a regex for the date if the first meta__val is the date*, the pages are obviously the same template or the OP would not be using one approach so logically you won't be seeing them switch places,  as far as the transcript__para__time, there is no reason at all for a regex, the tag has a class.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I see the utility of getting the first meta_val for the date -- I didn't know BS grabbed the first thing: that is a *sweet* bit of news! But there are dozens of instances of the `<data class='talk-transcript__para__time'>`, and I want the last one, so, for the very reasons you specify, `time = soup.select_one("data.talk-transcript__para__time").text` doesn't work. Which would be great, but having it work for the first one, and thus making the code that much cleaner is very good news! Thanks for the help. And my thanks to both you and @rock321987 for the great discussion.